# Null rows is also read when reading data from excel sheet dynamically

Tags: excel, ssis, vba

```
endofrow  = excelWorksheet.get_Range("X3", "Y3").get_End(XlDirection.xlDown).Row.ToString();
//endofrow value must be 5 but it comes as 8 and null rows appear
```

this function must read only 2 rows as only two rows of data are present ,but it reads extra rows and null rows are appearing during insertion.

Comment: check if there is space or invisible characters in the empty cells.

Comment: @RajnikantSharma ,I already checked and tried clearing the contents of cells and deleting them also.Still no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code to return last row. hope this might help you

```
Sub GetLastRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lRow = 1
    End If
End With

MsgBox "The last row in Sheet1 which has data is " & lRow
End Sub
```

you can change it according to your need.